# How to create xml in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-xdk

How to create xml in oracle using sql query.

Comment: You'll probably get more responses—and they'll probably be better—if you provide more context around your question.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb13gen.htm#i1027254